# Thermal equilibrium of objects in deep space

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, cosmic-microwave-background

I've read somewhere (not a reliable source though) that an object in space and far enough away from any heat source other than the CMB would eventually cool to 3K, the CMB's temperature, but no colder.

I wonder why that should be the case.

The amount of energy the object gains from the CMB over time doesn't only depend on its temperature, but also its intensity. If you double the amount of CMB there is, it should increase the amount the object is heated up, even though the frequency did not necessarily change.

That doesn't mean it's not the case, as maybe it's just the right amount, but it's not obvious to me what's going on.

Comment: How can it get colder (or stay warmer) than its surrounding?

Comment: @Alchimista It has no surroundings except the CMB, which is just radiation. Radiation temperature is defined by the black body spectrum, so the intensity could be arbitrarily low from that piece of information alone.

Comment: Your object is *within* the CMB. Besides this cosmological  precisation, the same will be with a localised source. Look at radiative heat transfer in Wikipedia.  Your discerning about intensities only affects the time in which eq. is attained.

Comment: @Alchimista I don't think so. If you shield the object from every other photon of the CMB, do you not think that would lower the objects eventual temperature? But this reduced radiation has the same spectrum.

Comment: Of course it will lower the T heating up the shield. But thanks to the more detailed answer below you got my point. Still even with point sources there is no transfer of heat without T difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider the radiation from a point source then the energy per unit area falls off as $1/r^2$. For sources with a more complicated shape there may be a different power dependence near to the object, but in general the power falls with distance. With objects like this the radiation temperature and intensity are not fixed relative to each other.

However the CMB is different because it doesn't have a single source. The CMB comes from everywhere in space. Technically it is isotropic and homogeneous. That means the intensity of the CMB radiation your object receives is the the same as if it were immersed in a fluid with a temperature of 3K (more precisely 2.725K) so the temperature and the intensity are fixed relative to each other. The energy per unit area your object receives from the CMB is fixed at the value given by Stefan's law for a temperature of 3K.

And that's why an object far from any other energy sources will equilibrate to the same temperature as the CMB.

Comment: "...as if it were immersed in a fluid with a temperature of 3K..." I think I now realize why that is: The CMB *is* black body radiation, coming from particles uniformly heated in the early universe - hence its intensity must match the spectrum.